# If $Y$ is contractible then any continuous map $f: X \to Y$ is null-homotopic.

Tags: algebraic-topology

if Y be a Contractile then any Continuous map $f:X \to Y$ is null homotopic?

Comment: I seen that there may be an english barrier that forced the question to be a bit confusing, however you should read the relevant latex formatting for posting.

Comment: well.yes my english not good. thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $Y$ is contractible then there is a homotopy $H: Y \times I \to Y$ such that $H(x,0) = \textbf{id}_Y$ and $H(x,1) = x_0$ where $x_0 \in Y$ and we let $x_0$ denote the constant map $y \mapsto x_0$. If $f: X \to Y$ is continuous we take $G(x,t) = H(f(x),t)$. Then $G$ is continuous and $G(x,0) = H(f(x),0) = f$ and $G(x,1) = H(f(x),1) = x_0 $ i.e $f$ is null-homotopic.

$\textbf{Question}$:Why does $f$ being continuous imply that $G$ is continuous?